# 24 bit Alpha Channel in Base64_encode

Tags: css, png, base64, alpha, data-uri

So I am experimenting with using icons in my CSS using base64 encoded pngs. I have used http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp to convert them. However, the pngs only have an 8bit alpha channel, the pixels are either fully opaque, or fully transparent, no partial transparency. This is leaving my icons with hard edges. Any ideas of a 24bit alpha channel is possible through base64_encode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The encoder in that page may be buggy. I made a PNG with alpha channels in Photoshop, encoded it using PHP's `base64_encode()`, put it in an image, and it works. Take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/P3gLv/1) for HTML and [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/hb2Ug/1) for CSS.

Comment: I just looked at the code for my fiddles and realized how long the data URIs are for a mere 64x64 icon of a circle with a shadow...